# Reversing a string only showing the first character, and on multiple lines....why?

Tags: c#, reverse

trying a coding exercise here, C#. I am trying to reverse a string and I think I almost got it but it is only returning the first letter of the string. In the visual studios debugging console, it shows it in reverse but it shows it as a column for some reason, not on the same line. This is my code:

string word = "grate";

```
        var str = word.ToCharArray();

        for (var i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str[i].ToString());
        }
```

On a webpage it is only showing the first letter, I dont know if it is in reverse or not, but why doesn't it show on one line in the debugging console? It is coming up like this :

```
e
t
a
r
g
```

instead of this: `etarg` --- on the same line which is what I want

Also before you ask, I do not want to use the built in reverse method ".Reverse" so please don't suggest that. I am trying to do it manually

Comment: Ok well after I posted this question, it changed the format of how I wrote it. the debugging console shows the word like this                                                                                                                  e                                                                                                                                                      t                                                                                                                                                               a (no more room!) how do I write this on new lines

Comment: If you have further clarification, [edit] your question and add the content there, not it comments.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` does just that; it write the given string and then a new line. That's why it shows up on separate lines. Use `Console.Write` to have them show up on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Console.WriteLine(str[i].ToString());
```

to

```
Console.Write(str[i].ToString());
```

Writeline is appending a new line to every character, that's why it's showing up in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`Console.Write(str[i].ToString());`

and that will help yo

Answer (score 0):

You might read up on the difference between [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0) and [`Console.Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-5.0).

Further, those methods know how to write a character: you don't need to convert the character to a string, so `Console.Write(str[i])` will emit the character specified.

Try something like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    
  public static string StrRev( string s )
  {
    char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
    char   temp ;
    
    int    i = -1 ;
    int    j = chars.Length ;
    
    while ( ++i < --j )
    {
      temp     = chars[i] ;
      chars[i] = chars[j] ;
      chars[j] = temp     ;
    }
  
    string r = new String(chars);
    return r ;
  }
    
  public static void Main()
  {
    string s = "1234567890";
    string r = StrRev(s);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    Console.WriteLine(r);
  }

}
```